# Word for curiosity motivated by the negative acts of others

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for curiosity that is a prompted by learning of someone's misdeeds or something negative in general? For example, if I discovered that my neighbor had recently been to prison and as a result I  became curious about his past.

Comment: "Nosy" might be appropriate.

Comment: There could be various reasons behind this curiosity. Are you looking to get your neighbour arrested? Are you repulsed and horrified? Or did you think they were boring but now you discover their misdeeds they become more interesting? Do you have a new-found respect for them? Do you find yourself obsessed with thoughts of them, either through fear or attraction or otherwise? Maybe [Hybristophilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybristophilia)?

Comment: I should have mentioned that in the post @StuartF. The type of curiosity I am asking about is motivated from learning something disappointing but wanting or needing to learn more as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a word for curiosity that is a prompted by learning of someone's misdeeds or something negative in general?

I don't think so: English would normally describe the type of curiosity by the use an adjective:

OED

> **Morbid** curiosity -
>
> (adj.)  2. Of a person, mental state, etc.: **characterized** by
> excessive gloom or apprehension, or (in later use) **by an unhealthy
> preoccupation with disease, death, or other disturbing subject**;
> given to unwholesome brooding.
>
> 1990   M. Freeland Kenneth Williams 116   *Ken particularly used to
> enjoy the murder trials—not for any morbid curiosity, but for the drama unfolding.*

**Prurient** curiosity -

> **A.** adj.  **1. Exhibiting or characterized by excessive or inappropriate desire or interest; overly curious.** Frequently with
> overtones of sense A. 2.
>
> 1994   Newsday (Nexis) 21 Aug. 38   *The documentary triggers in the
> reader a mixed feeling of disgust for and prurient fascination with
> the lifestyle of the rich and famous.*
>
> **A 2**. **Lascivious, lewd; exhibiting or characterized by an excessive or inappropriate concern with sexual matters; encouraging
> such a concern.**
>
> 2006   Daily Tel. (Nexis) 22 Apr. 12   *At the risk of appearing
> prurient, I had to inquire: how erotic was it?*

Comment: Well, there's *prurience.* "Prurient" was the first word which came to mind for me.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure "prurience" is sufficiently limited to curiosity or incorporates "ghoulishness".

Answer (score 0):

This is ***investigative*** or ***inquisitive*** behaviour. The first is the better fit to your question, and the latter is a more general description that may be appropriate if your behaviour became known.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/investigative)
> *investigative* adjective
> relating to the discovery of information about something, especially something that may be illegal

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inquisitive)
> *inquisitive* adjective
> the quality of wanting to discover as much as you can about things, sometimes in a way that annoys people

More colloquially, you are being ***snoopy***

> Merriam Webster
> snoopy adjective (snoopier; snoopiest)
> given to snooping especially for personal information about others

You are snooping:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snoop)
> snoop
> to try to find out about other people's private lives